# Why my Curl command is failing inside a docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, curl, docker-compose

I am running a python based server inside a container. I can access it inside my host machine

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"uid":"admin","password":"admin"}' http://localhost:9000/auth
```

Result:

```
{"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTA4Mjk1NDAsImlhdCI6MTU5MDgyNTk0MCwibmJmIjoxNTkwODI1OTQwLCJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiJ9.iTexlDupUMYYrodw44GI9ZnsTXnl5MurAXq6JCfqM0A"}
```

But now i am trying to do same curl inside another container, But It gives me access denied error.

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x564809d7ff50)
* Uses proxy env variable http_proxy == 'http://10.223.4.20:911'
*   Trying 10.223.4.20...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x564809d7ff50)
* Connected to 10.223.4.20 (10.223.4.20) port 911 (#0)
> POST http://localhost:9000/auth HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 34
> 
* upload completely sent off: 34 out of 34 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 642
< 
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Access Denied (policy_denied)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your system policy has denied access to the requested URL.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">

</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host 10.223.4.20 left intact
```

All the containers are mapped as  `network_mode: host`.

Here is my Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:


  tacotron:
    image: tacotron-image
    network_mode: host
    command: python3 runserver.py

  tts_driver:
    image: tts_driver
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    environment: 
      - ASR_PUB_PORT=5555
      - ASR_PUB_TOPIC=subnlptopic
      - TTS_DRIVER_PUB_PORT=5556
      - TTS_DRIVER_PUB_TOPIC=pubttstopic
    command: python3 /app/TTSDriver.py
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Thanks
Akshay

Comment: Could you please post the output of `curl` with `verbose` mode?

Comment: Please edit this question to include a [mcve].  That especially includes the Python code that makes the request.  If you can strip out all but one of the containers in the `docker-compose.yml` file, and remove unusual options like `privileged:` and `network_mode:`, that's also very helpful to narrowing down the actual problem.

Comment: @hariK I have posted the verbose output

Comment: @DavidMaze network mode is required for accessing the the port outside the container.